# WCF System.TypeLoadException: Access is denied:

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a self-hosted WCF server that works very well on my dev machine.

However when I run it on my Windows 2012 server I have this error:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Access is denied: 'Castle.DynamicProxy.Internal.CompositionInvocation'.
```

This error appeared when I migrated my 4.5 service to .net 4.8
Any clue?

Added : This is the failing starting code :

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding
        {
            Security =
            {
                Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport
            },
            MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
            MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue,
            OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
            CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
            SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
            ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
        };
        var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(Configuration.PmsUrl);
        var client = new WebServiceRouterSoapClient(binding, endpointAddress);
        client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new LoggingEndpointBehaviour());

        try
        {
            var response = action(client);
            client.Close();
            if(response.ExceptionCode > 0)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Exception {response.ExceptionCode} - {response.ExceptionDescription}");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.GetLog().Error(ex);
            client.Abort();
        }
```

Thank you. Jonathan

Comment: You can take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/deploying-an-internet-information-services-hosted-wcf-service

Comment: May be i'm wrong, but my service is NOT hosted into IIS

Comment: Can you provide some configuration of your service? In the state of version 4.5, can your service run successfully on windows server2012, but there are errors after switching to version 4.8?

Comment: just added the faulty code.thx!